# Is it possible to transfer ownership of Chromecast apps?

Tags: google-cast

Have been trying to contact Google Cast support on this, but no response there. Hoping there are someone able to answer or point me in the right direction here.

We have a couple of Chromecast apps developed for a client. These are registered on a Google account we currently own and which is also used for other apps and clients (let's not get into a hindsight discussion about the cleverness of this setup right now).

I am simply wondering if there is a way to transfer ownership of these apps to the client's Google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer the apps to a different account. Please reach out to us here: https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?visit_id=637100530319223284-3107522626&hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Thanks for the response, Anjaneesh. I've tried that form twice, without any response. That's why I came here. Are you part of the team supervising the requests via this form, or do you know the team in charge? If so, I'd really appreciate if you were able to follow on any of my submitted requests.

Comment: I see now that I have 1. been checking the wrong Google-account for responses, and 2. managed to type my work-email incorrectly, which results in the answer not reaching me there (FACEPALM). So ignore any statement that a response has not been given, and accept my apologies. Found the answer now and will follow up with client to get the transfer sorted. Thanks again for your help :)